# Changes feed: sometimes no modified object are notified

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

It used to work with changes feed and it work perfectly in 99% of cases, but sometimes it incorrectly include some file that neither me or my collaborators had changed.

The response with the "updated" entry report that

- updatedEntry is the correct OLD date
- published is the correct OLD date
- modifiedByMe is the correct OLD date

BUT

- lastViewed is similar to the request date
- ACLFeed/updated is similar to the request date
- Each entry inside the ACLFeed/updated is similar to the request date

How is possible that I receive a notification for this entry?

Does the feed changes include entries just because the "lastViewed" date has changed?

If so, why the feedACL and the feedACL entries have a different "updated" date?

Comment: Do you know if the the ACL entries are similar to the old ones? A change the ACL might have triggered a change.

Comment: I think the lastViewed field triggered the change, I don't understand way the feed ACL and its entries have a different date.